# OSX - Detect when Finder is started

Tags: macos, finder

How can my app know that Finder has started? Is there any event that could help with this?

I thought about enumerating processes and look for Finder but this seems too heavy to do every X seconds. Is there any other way?

Comment: Huh? The Finder is always running isn't it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Some apps restart Finder so that's why one would need to know when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the notifications that `NSWorkspace` posts to its notification center (`-[NSWorkspace notificationCenter]`). For example, it posts `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` when a GUI app is launched. That notification's `userInfo` dictionary has, under the key `NSWorkspaceApplicationKey`, an instance of `NSRunningApplication` for the newly-launched app. You can check the `bundleIdentifier` of that to see if it equals "com.apple.finder".

Comment: Does this work for all kinds of apps or only for Cocoa apps? For example, would this work in a console app or an app with no GUI?

Comment: A) You asked about the Finder. B) You could try reading the docs for `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` which explains its limitations. (It only works for foreground GUI apps.) C) Those docs recommend an alternative technique to learn about background-only and `LSUIElement` apps. D) You *really* would not want something that notified you of every process (e.g. console program) that's launched or terminates. Those happens all the time on a system like OS X.

Comment: I think I wasn't really clear in my question. Sorry about that. I was asking from my app's point of view. Does my app need to be a Cocoa app or it can also be an app without a GUI/console app and also receive the notification?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Your app will have to link against AppKit or Cocoa. It will have to run the main thread's run loop. It doesn't need to be a bundled app. I don't think it needs to create an `NSApplication` object or call `NSApplicationMain()` or `-[NSApplication run]`.