# Get notify when Finder PID is change

Tags: macos, pid, finder

I just want to get notify when Finder.app PID is change.
For a traditional method, I just polling to check whether ID is changed or not.
Instead of polling shall we have any other way to do.

Note: I tried with NSNotificationCenter and NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification. It works, but it is also need polling like NSRunLoop. I wanna get notify without any mode of polling.

```
- (void)appHasLaunched:(NSNotification *)notif
{
NSRunningApplication *runApp = [[notif userInfo] valueForKey:@"NSWorkspaceApplicationKey"];
  if ([runApp.bundleIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.apple.finder"])
  {
    NSLog(@"start");
  }
}



    ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [ws notificationCenter];
    [notifyCenter addObserver:self
                     selector:@selector(appHasLaunched:)
                         name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification 
                       object:nil];
```

The above code works perfectly, but it demands a loop for continuous observation
for Example,

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OSX - Detect when Finder is started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033894/osx-detect-when-finder-is-started)

Comment: I tried with NSNotificationCenter, but it din't works.

Comment: Did you use the notification center **from** `NSWorkspace`? You can't use `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`.

Comment: Yes, I used, it works too, but this one also need polling for observe.

Comment: It does not need polling. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @KenThomases: yes it needs,  please see the above code, and tell me how it does not need. Thanks

Comment: Right, there needs to be a run loop "running", but that doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. A run loop does not poll nor busy-loop. The thread blocks and the kernel unblocks it when one of its input sources has input. How do you expect to get notified of an event if you don't have some mechanism for monitoring the event, sleeping until it occurs, and getting woken up and called when it occurs? That's exactly what a run loop does. Do you imagine that the system can call a function of yours when your thread is already in the middle of other work? It can't.

Comment: @KenThomases:  Oh ok, I had a thought that the run loop is kind of busy-loop. Now it is cleared. Thank you so much.